# read markers of .wav file

Tags: python, audio, wav, markers

I would like to use **markers** in .wav files.

It seems to be supported by `aifc` module with `getmarkers()` : http://docs.python.org/2/library/aifc.html#aifc.aifc.getmarkers (for .aiff files), but not for `wave` module (http://docs.python.org/2/library/wave.html?highlight=wave#wave.Wave_read.getmarkers).

How could we **read markers** of .wav files ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit**: here is an updated version of `scipy.io.wavfile` that adds many things (24 bit .wav files support for read/write, cue markers, cue markers labels, and some other metadata like pitch (if defined), etc.):

[wavfile.py (enhanced)](https://gist.github.com/josephernest/3f22c5ed5dabf1815f16efa8fa53d476)

Feel free to share it!

---

I finally found a solution (it uses some function of scipy.io.wavfile) :

```
def readmarkers(file, mmap=False):
    if hasattr(file,'read'):
        fid = file
    else:
        fid = open(file, 'rb')
    fsize = _read_riff_chunk(fid)
    cue = []
    while (fid.tell() < fsize):
        chunk_id = fid.read(4)
        if chunk_id == b'cue ':
            size, numcue = struct.unpack('<ii',fid.read(8))
            for c in range(numcue):
              id, position, datachunkid, chunkstart, blockstart, sampleoffset = struct.unpack('<iiiiii',fid.read(24))
              cue.append(position)
        else:
            _skip_unknown_chunk(fid)
    fid.close()
    return cue
```

Feel free to add it into Scipy's `wavfile.py` if someone is interested.

Comment: My markers are of type 'range' (id,start,end,duration ?). With your function I can only read the start position of each range. How can I modify your function in order to make it work for range too ?

Comment: This is the reference that I used : http://www.sonicspot.com/guide/wavefiles.html ... Where are stored your markers of type `range` ?  In `Cue Chunk` (http://www.sonicspot.com/guide/wavefiles.html#cue) or `Playlist Chunk` (http://www.sonicspot.com/guide/wavefiles.html#plst) ?

Comment: In case it may help someone, your code was working good for me but it raised an exception in _skip_unknown_chunk because it was finding something it could not read. Since this was happening after the markers were correctly read I just added a break after the for loop :) (I added markers with adobe audition)

Comment: Was this ever submitted to scipy?

Comment: Yes it's here: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/6852 and another version here https://github.com/X-Raym/wavfile.py

Answer (score -2):

it is in wave.Wave_read modules, called `Wave_read.getmarkers()`
see the docs for detail:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/wave.html?highlight=wave#wave.Wave_read.getmarkers

Comment: I honestly can't understand why this doesn't raise `NotImplemented` instead

Comment: FWIW, if you want to implement this yourself, there's a lot of good information [here](http://home.roadrunner.com/~jgglatt/tech/wave.htm) (see the section on cue points)

Comment: I don't have enough skills (yet) about how to open files, go somewhere specific in a file, extract a chunk, etc. to do it myself unfortunately... 
About `NotImplemented`, how can we set it to this status `NotImplemented` ?

Comment: Do you think you could help me @goncalopp?

Comment: @Basj I don't have much time ATM, nor do I have access to a wave file with known markers. If you can send me one I may be able to come up with something in a day or two. Otherwise, this is a great opportunity to learn about [open](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open), [files](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) and [struct](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html)

Comment: that's what I finally did, and I learnt lots of interesting things on open, files, and struct! (see my answer)