# Reading Wave (.wav) markers or cues in Java using OpenAL

Tags: java, wav, markers, openal, cue-points

I have a wave file which includes markers that are set using www.reaper.fm. These markers are to be used to determine whether a fade in/out point has been reached during playback. I am using OpenAL to play the wave file and cannot figure out how to read markers or cues defined in the file.

I found a similar question for [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20011239/read-markers-of-wav-file) but can't find a proper example for Java or OpenAL. I'd also be open to other Java APIs if needed.