# How to name channels/tracks in my *.wav files?

Tags: python, wav, audacity

I am creating and writing `*.wav` files using the `wavefile` Python package (source code on Github [here](https://github.com/vokimon/python-wavefile)). When I open these files in Audacity and display the track/channel names, they have default names of the format `{filename} 1`, `{filename} 2`, `{filename} 3`,... and so on, as shown in the below screenshot. Is there a way to customize these names in Python using the `wavefile` module, or any other module such that Audacity shows those names?

[image]

Comment: When exporting a .WAV, are you able to have tracks' names be stored in the file, and then open the .WAV file and get the names back? If not, then the solution for your question probably won't work for Audacity. Some audio programs recognize markers and other non-audio custom data that people typically store with a .WAV, but there's nothing in the file format standard indicating the channels' names. You could potentially use markers, but Audacity might not support them: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20396562/6273251 Also what research have you done so far on the .WAV format?

Comment: No, renaming the track in Audacity, exporting it as another `.wav` file, and re-opening in Audacity did not preserver the name. 
Regarding research on the format, I know you can store metadata such as title, album, source, etc.

Comment: Okay so if even Audacity can't read its own track names, what do you expect to be able to do differently in Python? Audacity has its own project file format, AUP, which surely would preserve the track names; is there a reason you can't work with that format instead?

Comment: Well, if you read my question carefully, I'm specifically asking if there's something I can add to the .WAV format programmatically that will preserve channel/track names, similar to what is done with metadata. 
Regarding using Audacity's project file format, I'm not aware of an API/SDK for programmatically generating these types of files.

Comment: So you're actually asking how to do it in general, not just Audacity? Or how you can do it and have it work in Audacity (without changing Audacity's source code)?

Comment: @RandomDavis The latter.

Comment: So to be clear, you want to modify a .WAV file to have Audacity be able to read the custom track/channel names, when Audacity itself can't do that? Well, good luck...